# Workflow for Lead Owner Field Update does not fire

Tags: workflow, leads

Some leads from our website forms were assigned to "website" as the lead owner regardless our default owner setting is me. The form is web-to-lead form but not using SFDC code.

While working with our webmaster figuring out the reason, I create a workflow rule on Lead object to have a "lead owner" field update if the lead owner field equals "website", then it should update the "lead owner" field to my name. After I activated the rule, and changed a lead owner to "website", the workflow didn't seem to fire at all. I checked the monitoring debug log too, nothing showed up.Please advice! Thanks!

Jeny

Comment: What's the criteria on your workflow ?

Comment: What do you mean the form is web-to-lead but not using SFDC code? Is it a Visualforce page?

Comment: Perhaps your logic needs to be that if its not assigned to the other lead owners you've specified, then it gets assigned to you?

Comment: @Greenstork, we had a webmaster coded the form and the communication to SFDC, and now I am working on using SFDC web-to-lead HTML code to replace the ones they have. I thought the point of using SFDC is to save webmaster's energy to build it from scratch, but since they already did, is there benefit to switch it over? Anyway, we are in the process of switching it to using SFDC WTL form.

Comment: @crmprogdev, Thank you, I will give it a try, but why would that make a difference?

Comment: @techtrekker, the only critera I have is "lead owner equals website". is it still true that a lookup field can't be used in workflow rules? which is my case. The field I want the workflow rule to update is "lead owner" which is a lookup field. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeny, looks like there are many with far more experience than I have who are trying to help. I suggest you try to follow their advice. My reasoning was to trap anything that wasn't already explicitly assigned to others. You're clearly in good hands. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Standard Web-to-lead forms can take advantage of Lead Assignment Rules.  These rules basically govern the assignment of ownership based on the criteria that you setup.  Once you have your new Web-to-Lead form in place using standard web-to-lead, you can setup Assignment Rules.

Regarding your workflow rule and custom web integration, it's hard to debug without seeing the actual rule logic itself, and understanding the exact architecture of the website integration.  Does it use a Visualforce page, does it use the Salesforce API, etc.?

Comment: I am still learning the history of our website.... right now we have a out-sourced webmaster manage it, which I have no idea what they use... not Visualforce for sure...we tried to use Assignment Rules, but since we have 40+ reps in the nation and they are zipcode based, we'll write hundreds of rules. This is my next project to maybe build a custom object "zipcode" then related this object to lead and account to achieve auto assignment for ownership. Any advice on this? sorry, my questions are scattered...

Comment: I guess I'm not following, how are assignment rules more complex than your suggested workflow rule? Can you post your workflow rule logic? Are you using a formula to set the owner value?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not a developer so maybe I am at the wrong place. I use the click and drop built in work flow function in SFDC set up a field update work flow... Since what I want is to update the "lead owner" field to be me if "lead owner equals to website". Can it be achieved w/o writing codes? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you absolutely could and that would be one lead assignment rule as well. As we've noted, it's hard to debug your workflow rule without actually seeing it.  Can you either take a screen shot or post the logic of the rule the way it is written on the workflow rule record itself. Also, how is the workflow rule evaluated?

Comment: Where I'm getting confused, is that your workflow rule appears to set everything to one owner, yet you said you couldn't use lead assignment rules because you would need it set to 40+ owners. These two statements don't appear to reconcile.